# How to get rid of two extra blank lines using js-beautify with html?

Tags: javascript, html, atom-editor, js-beautify

I am using js-beautify 1.6.4 on Windows from within an Atom text editor package to format some HTML.

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style media="screen">
      p {
        color: #444;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Some paragraph written in a WYSIWYG editor</p>
    <h1>HEADER written in a WYSIWYG editor</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here are the options that I pass into the beautifier:

```
{
    end_with_newline: false,
    eol: "\n",
    extra_liners: [],
    indent_inner_html: true,
    indent_size: 2,
    preserve_newlines: true,
    wrap_attributes_indent_size: 1,
    wrap_line_length: 80
}
```

And here is the HTML I get as output:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style media="screen">
      p {
        color: #444;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Some paragraph written in a WYSIWYG editor</p>
    <h1>HEADER written in a WYSIWYG editor</h1>


  </body>
</html>
```

What I don't understand is why two extra blank lines are added. Is there an option I'm missing or misunderstanding, or another way I should be doing things?